# Copy child entities from one object to another

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im using EF and have a hierarchical structure like:

```
Father
---- Child
---------Grandchildren
------------great grandchild
```

(It's actually a little more complex)

What I need is "copy" the childs (and all his descendants) from one object to another.

For example, something like

```
add_descendants(ExistingFather,NewFather)
```

I know how to do it with nested foreach´s but it´s a complex structure I want to know if there´s a better way to do this kind of operations. thanks.

Comment: Could you not just do it with LinQ and something like `thisGrandfather.Children = thatGrandfather.Select(x=>x.Children.Clone());`

Comment: Based on your description we can only give simple examples which aren't likely do cover your "complex structure". In other words: we can only help if you show a real-life example (or a close substitute) and explain where the shoe pinches.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i am able to understand your requirements. But if i understood you correctly, why don't you directly assign the values from one object to another.

Something Like this :-

```
var NewFather = ExistingFather;
```

Comment: What I need is
 Father NewFather = new Father();
 NewFather.childs = ExistingFather.childs; // and all descendants
db.Fathers.add(NewFather );
db.saveChanges();